# Why the "Sign-in error" notification appear on Xiaomi device?

Tags: notifications, xiaomi

Since yesterday, I've been getting this error message and I have no idea what application it is. I checked all of my installed apps and can't see it.

Can you help me identify this icon?

[image]

Comment: What does pressing and holding the notification show? In most cases you would be shown the app name a button to access its app info.

Comment: I pressed the notification and it took me to 'android system' notifications settings and when I tap on it it asks me to enter password

Answer (score 3):

You must be using Xiaomi device with stock ROM. When you first switched on device, you created an online Mi account like Google account. Now this device is attached to that Mi account to avoid misuse in case of phone theft. This phenomenon is similar to [FRP](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6172890) implemented by [other OEMs](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/frp/) too.
Shown number `178...` is your [Mi account ID](https://account.xiaomi.com/pass/register). This error is appearing because device is unable to verify your identity online due to no internet access or something like that. Go to `Mi Account` in `Settings` and login again.

Be careful! If you are unable to login, you won't be able to access device on reboot.

See [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/info-android-device-security-privacy-t3637290) to know a little bit about how FRP works.

Comment: This works, I logged back into my MI account and the notification was gone.

Answer (score 1):

You might have logged in from another device and changed the password of your google account. If it wasn't you, you can change the password again and then go to my accounts in Google and click the option log out from all devices and then sign-in in your required devices.